# Duda sobre un ejercicio de matrices y bucles en Python

Tags: python, bucles, matrices

El ejercicio se basa en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para crear la matriz usé el siguiente código, la duda me surge en la pregunta del bucle que usaría (segunda parte de la pregunta 8), ¿Qué código debería usar para crear un bucle y recorra la matriz?

```
import numpy as np
print("Concepto / Fecha / Gasto\n")
gastos = np.array([["Disposición de efectivo en cajero", "18/05/11", "60.00 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "18/05/11", "56.00 €"],
                   ["Recibo de fundaciones y o.n.g", "18/05/11", "25.00 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en medicina", "17/05/11", "45.31 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "17/05/11", "60.00 €"]])
print(gastos, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo, entiendo.

Hay una manera de recorrer una matriz, y la mejor forma es implementa un `for`.

Si tenemos un objeto llamado `arreglo` que a su vez tiene objetos dentro, podemos deducir lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
print("Concepto / Fecha / Gasto\n")
gastos = np.array([["Disposición de efectivo en cajero", "18/05/11", "60.00 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "18/05/11", "56.00 €"],
                   ["Recibo de fundaciones y o.n.g", "18/05/11", "25.00 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en medicina", "17/05/11", "45.31 €"],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "17/05/11", "60.00 €"]])
print(gastos, "\n")

 print(gastos[1])
```

Esto claramente imprimirá el objeto número 1 del array, tomando en cuenta que en programación, el conteo inicia desde "0"

Aunque también podemos acceder a los gastos directamente de cada objeto, ¿cómo?

`print (gastos[0][2])`

Ahí nos arrojará: "60.00 €".

Ahora bien, implementando funciones iterativas que recorran matrices, comencemos con el `for`.

```
i=0
j=2
for i in range(len(gastos)):
    print(gastos[i][j])
```

Eso te arrojará lo siguiente únicamente los gastos debido a que estás jugando con las pociones del array y de sus listas.

Lo que tocaría ahora sería implementar un if, tomando esos valores, convertirlos en enteros y comparar si son mayores a "50 €"

```
import numpy as np
print("Concepto / Fecha / Gasto\n")
gastos = np.array([["Disposición de efectivo en cajero", "18/05/11", 60.00],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "18/05/11", 56.00],
                   ["Recibo de fundaciones y o.n.g", "18/05/11", 25.00],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en medicina", "17/05/11", 45.31],
                   ["Pago con tarjeta en gasolineras", "17/05/11", 60.00]])
# print(gastos, "\n")
#se inicializan variables para luego trabajar con ellas

i=0
j=2
x=[]

#se utiliza el for in range para tomar en cuenta la longitud del array principal
for i in range(len(gastos)):

#los datos encontrados se colocan en una lista de variable "x"
    x.append(gastos[i][j])

#los datos de la lista se convierten a enteros
    b = [*map(float, x)]

#luego se realiza el if dado los datos obtenidos con el código anterior
    if b[i] >= 50.0:
      print ("Los mayores de 50 €:",(b[i]))
      i+1
    # else:
    #   print ("Este no es mayor a 50 €", (b[i]))
```

Tomando en cuenta que la matriz le hice un leve cambio, decidí quitarle las comillas y dejar los números enteros en cada lista(el valor).

También debo decir que este no es un código pulido pero funciona de acuerdo a lo que se pide.

Si quieres mostrar los que no son mayores, sólo des-comenta el `else`

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Comment: Me ha surgido otras dudas: 1-Una característica del array o arreglo es que sus elementos son del mismo tipo de datos, entonces ¿cómo es válido el caso donde tomas los precios como números flotantes en vez de cadenas de caracteres?.     2-En el bucle for, el "i = 0" no sobraría?, pues aún no sé mucho de los bucles for, pero si no mal recuerdo, la variable que se indica luego del for es una variable totalmente nueva que no se ha definido anteriormente.            3-Y que valores debo asignarle a j o qué código debo escribir para que me recorra toda la matriz en vez de sólo los gastos?

Comment: Para utilizar y hacer comparaciones como es pedido en el ejercicio, es justo y necesario tratar los precios como enteros, o flotantes, ya que es justo y necesario, no se le puede agregar otro símbolo. 

Lo que se intenta lograr con "i" y con "j" es una posición en específico, en este caso. "i" será la variable que va a recorrer el array. Este te dirá Bueno, para la longitud del array, que es igual a "4" recórrelo y para "j" que son los gastos, recorrerá la misma cantidad de veces y lo guardará en una lista llamada "x" y desde ahí es que se hará un "if" para comparar si es mayor o no a 50.

Comment: "i"cumple la función de recorrer por haberle pasado el parámetro len(gastos) teniendo gastos [4] posiciones. Cabe destacar que "len" es la longitud del array, entonces lo recorrerá tantas posiciones haya en el array y como en este caso hay [4] recorrerá cada uno de ellos, por eso también se le suma "1" a la variable "i" paraq ue aumente la posición y ya no tome el que tomó sino el siguiente a ese. Y "j" se le iguala a 2 para que se coloque en la posición de los gastos. Lo único que se hace aquí, es jugar con las posiciones.

Comment: Si quieres que "j" recorra la matriz en vez de sólo los gastos, debes declararla igual como declaro "i": for j in range(len(gastos)). Ahí tomará la posición [0], la [1] y así sucesivamente. Espero haberte ayudado. 

Valórame también con un "respuesta útil" en la flechita si te he ayudado en algo. 

@Sebtres321

Comment: Vale, ya comprendo el tema del for en esta ocasión, y estoy agradecido, me ha sido de gran utilidad, pero aún sigo sin entender lo de definir el "i = 0" ¿No se supondría que esa variable ya se definiría por defecto al momento de hacer el bucle? Empezando por el número 0

Answer (score 0):

El bucle `for` estándar de Python, sin embargo la forma de iterar sobre la matriz puede cambiar:

De esta forma itera sobre cada arreglo de forma independiente:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

for x in arr:
  print(x)
```

Salida:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
```

Y de esta forma sobre cada elemento como un escalar:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

for x in arr:
  for y in x:
    print(y)
```

Salida:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

También convendría echarle un vistazo a la función `nditer()` de numpy:

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])

for x in np.nditer(arr):
  print(x)
```